# SearchView in Actionbar Appcompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

In my application, I am using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` but I am facing a weird problem. I have created `SearchView` in `ActionBar` and has set its property `app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"`

> but the SearchView is not expanded or collapsed on touch.

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

I have tried different solutions but none worked. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change

```
android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

by

```
 app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

This worked for me

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.ipartie.views.activities.HomeActivity">
      <item
          android:id="@+id/search"
          android:title="@string/search"
          android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
          app:showAsAction="always"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```