# How to add search icon in action bar?

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am using navigation drawer,and i have action bar in all fragments,I am trying to add search icon in action bar but its not appearing,app is not crashing but even icon is not visible in my action bar,following is my code for that can any one help

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/searchs"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>



</menu>
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30566886/searchview-in-actionbar-appcompat/30566958#30566958

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is because of:

`android:showAsAction="never"`

instead of that use:

`android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Comment: is it possible to set clik listner on icon what i set in action bar??

Comment: i'm not sure about adding listener because i'm still beginner, but i think you are looking for something like this [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#Respond)

Answer (score 1):

ShowAsAction must be always or ifRoom.

```
always makes sure it is always present. 
ifRoom pushes the menuitem into overflow menu if space is not available.
```

if your intention is to attach search functionality to your activity, you should consider using `SearchView widget` instead of using and icon and handling click on it.

Answer (score 1):

```html
    @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contact, menu);
      MainActivityAfterLogin.menu = menu;

      MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
      SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
      SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
        .getActionView(searchItem);
      searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
        .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
      searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {

        return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {

        return false;
       }
      });

      return true;
     }



    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

      
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_search"
            android:title="@string/action_search"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

    </menu>

add this in manifest

 <activity
            android:name="**mainactivity**"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_invited_person_list" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value="**result activity**" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.w3nuts.rsvp.main.SearchResultActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_result" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```